# How come mount command is disabled inside a docker container

Tags: docker, mount

How can I avoid the following error message at the end of this docker session:

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
root@b3bcdc4551f5:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@b3bcdc4551f5:/# cd home/
root@b3bcdc4551f5:/home# ls
root@b3bcdc4551f5:/home# mkdir 1
root@b3bcdc4551f5:/home# mkdir 2
root@b3bcdc4551f5:/home# mount --bind 1 2
mount: block device /home/1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: cannot mount block device /home/1 read-only
```

Update:

```
$ docker run --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN -it ubuntu /bin/bash
root@1a6c069a8589:/# cd home/
root@1a6c069a8589:/home# mkdir 1
root@1a6c069a8589:/home# mkdir 2
root@1a6c069a8589:/home# mount --bind 1 2
mount: block device /home/1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: cannot mount block device /home/1 read-only
root@1a6c069a8589:/home# exit
$ docker run --cap-add=ALL -it ubuntu /bin/bash
root@1e04bcd81fee:/# cd home/
root@1e04bcd81fee:/home# mkdir 1
root@1e04bcd81fee:/home# mkdir 2
root@1e04bcd81fee:/home# mount --bind 1 2
mount: block device /home/1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: cannot mount block device /home/1 read-only
root@1e04bcd81fee:/home# exit
```

--privileged is all right though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Self answer:)
Disable apparmor using '`--security-opt apparmor:unconfine`d' would work.

Ref: [issue 16429](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16429)

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the recommendation in [issue 9950](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9950):

> You cannot call mount unless you have CAP_SYS_ADMIN, which is not available in the default container config.
>   You'd need to `docker run --cap-add SYS_ADMIN`

Comment: how to add this if running Pods using the kubernetes kubectl and not with docker command?

Comment: @AndreyDonald Using SecurityContext /  Capabilities (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/): see an example at https://www.weave.works/blog/container-capabilities-kubernetes/